# Pybind11: "ImportError: DLL not found" when trying to import *.pyd in Python Interpreter

Tags: python, c++, dll, importerror, dependency-walker

I built a `.pyd` in Visual Studio 2019 (Community) that provides a wrapper for some functionality that's only present in the LibRaw. The solution compiles successfully without any warnings or errors. The project uses LibRaw, OpenCV and pybind11 as well as `Python.h` and the corresponding `.lib`-file.

When i try to import the `.pyd` inside the Python Interpreter i get:

```
C:\Users\Tim.Hilt\source\repos\cr3_converter\Release>dir
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Acer
 Volumeseriennummer: EC36-E45E

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\Tim.Hilt\source\repos\cr3_converter\Release

22.01.2020  11:28    <DIR>          .
22.01.2020  11:28    <DIR>          ..
22.01.2020  11:28               808 cr3_converter.exp
22.01.2020  11:28         3.068.361 cr3_converter.iobj
22.01.2020  11:28           785.552 cr3_converter.ipdb
22.01.2020  11:28             1.908 cr3_converter.lib
22.01.2020  11:28         4.190.208 cr3_converter.pdb
22.01.2020  11:28           953.856 cr3_converter.pyd
31.10.2019  16:22        26.408.085 IMG_0482_raw.CR3
               7 Datei(en),     35.408.778 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 77.160.587.264 Bytes frei

C:\Users\Tim.Hilt\source\repos\cr3_converter\Release>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cr3_converter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cr3_converter: The specified module was not found.
>>> import cr3_converter.pyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cr3_converter: The specified module was not found.
>>>
```

The Paths to the needed `.dlls` (Python and OpenCV in this case; LibRaw was linked fully statically) are set in the system-path.

I ran Dependency-Walker, but could not find anything suspicious. [Here is the corresponding Dependency Walker image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GEohj5SJXkjmCYE0xcnH5s0u3iHrY4gU). I also tried out another tool ([Dependencies.exe](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), which is essentially a rewrite of Dependency Walker, but takes into account the `API-MS-WIN-CORE-....dlls`) and got an error, which looked like this:

[image]

When i hover over the missing `.dll`, i can see a `api-ms-win... module could not be found on disk`. I have searched and found the module and added its directory-path to the system-path. Now the module isn't highlighted red anymore, but the `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WS2_32.dll` (red highlight at top of screenshot) still shows to have missing imports. Could this be an issue?

How i've produced the `.pyd`:

- Created empty Visual Studio project (Win32; Python is also the 32-bit-installation)
- Changed project-settings to `.dll`-configuration and `.pyd`-fileextension
- Added include-paths to the header files for OpenCV, LibRaw and Pybind11
- Added paths and input files for the linker for OpenCV, LibRaw and Python3.8
- Built the solution (No Errors, No Warnings)
- Tried to import the resulting `.pyd` in the python-interpreter

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667556/pyd-file-fails-to-load-but-dependancywalker-comes-up-clean-and-procmon-shows), where the OP had the problem of different Python-`.dlls` being loaded by the library, but in my case the library referenced by Dependency Walker is the same as the one i have in my path-variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I quietly assumed, that Windows searches for `.dll`s in the same directories as the ones listed in the systems (/users) `PATH`-variable.

However, that is not the case, as [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) revealed. For now, i copied the missing `.dll`s to the folder that contains the `.pyd` and everything works.

Comment: Great! Thanks for posing this! I had a very similar problem to yours and ProcMon let me know what .dll files that python could not locate. In more recent versions of python, one can use os.add_dll_directory("path to dll folder") to add search path for dlls. No need to copy any of them now.

Comment: @stackoverblown happy to help!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to propose a more manageable way to solve the discussed issue.

**The short answer is:**
Specify all DLL's directories by [`os.add_dll_directory(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) before you `import` your `.pyd`-module.

**More details.**
One may inspect DLLs loading issues by `windbg` ([use](http://www.lopezruiz.net/2021/09/08-tracing-loadlibrary.htm) `ed ntdll!LdrpDebugFlags 1` command) or `gflags` ([run](https://www.variadic.xyz/2017/10/31/library-loading-issues-windows/) `gflags -i <your-app.exe> +sls`). Here is example output:

```
65d8:3868 @ 1347896937 - LdrLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: D:\dev\MyLib\MyLib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
65d8:3868 @ 1347896937 - LdrpLoadDllInternal - ENTER: DLL name: D:\dev\MyLib\MyLib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
65d8:3868 @ 1347896937 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: D:\dev\MyLib\MyLib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
65d8:3868 @ 1347896937 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
65d8:3868 @ 1347896937 - LdrpMinimalMapModule - ENTER: DLL name: D:\dev\MyLib\MyLib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
ModLoad: 00007ffe`47360000 00007ffe`473c5000   D:\dev\MyLib\MyLib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
65d8:3868 @ 1347896937 - LdrpMinimalMapModule - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
65d8:3868 @ 1347896953 - LdrpFindKnownDll - ENTER: DLL name: MyLib.dll
65d8:3868 @ 1347896953 - LdrpFindKnownDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpSearchPath - ENTER: DLL name: MyLib.dll
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpComputeLazyDllPath - INFO: DLL search path computed: D:\dev\MyLib;C:\Python310;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: D:\dev\MyLib\MyLib.dll
65d8:6c30 @ 1347896953 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Python310\MyLib.dll
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MyLib.dll
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpSearchPath - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
65d8:15e4 @ 1347896953 - LdrpProcessWork - ERROR: Unable to load DLL: "MyLib.dll", Parent Module: "D:\dev\MyLib\MyLib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd", Status: 0xc0000135
```

It is clearly seen that DLLs are looked for only in `D:\dev\MyLib;C:\Python310;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32` directories. This means, that Python ignores `%PATH%` and do not use `%PYTHONPATH`. I dare to assume some relation with [`Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb8b931385ba9df4e01f7dd3ce4575d49f60efdf/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#L1366) -- the [`LoadLibraryExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) is called there with some specific flags.

This limitations can be overcome by the Windows API's function [`AddDllDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory). One may call it to extend directories list where libraries are looked for.

Fortunately Python provides [`os.add_dll_directory(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) method to do this. One should specify all DLL's directories path by means of this method at first. Then `.pyd`-module will be loaded successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I don't use pybind11 anymore. I'll come back to your answer if I get back into the Python-game!